# Angular js input box typing and paused

Tags: angularjs, settimeout

Am new to angular js and using xmpp service with angular js,I have a situation where i need to send typing when user starts typing in input box and pause when user stops typing.

I have basic idea that i need to use $timeout,and have one variable like `vm.isTyping = false;`

i also have written some sort of platform for the same.

```
vm.isTyping = false;
vm.checkTyping = function(){
    $timeout(function() {
        vm.isTyping = true;
    },2000);

    if(!vm.isTyping){
        vm.sendTyping();
    } else{
        //
    }
};
```

This is the input field code:

```
<input type="text" placeHolder="Type a message here" 
    ng-model="vm.newMessage" 
    ng-blur="focusRemove(vm.newMessage,vm.contact)" 
    ng-change="vm.checkTyping()"
    ng-model-options="{'debounce': 500}" 
    ng-keydown="vm.onKeyDown($event)" auto-focus />
```

The problem i am facing is that i cannot send typing everytime when user presses any key,one typing is sent on first key press then i should send pause when user stop typing.

Can any one help me to implement code in angular js to achieve this.

Comment: I think you need to use watch and remove debounce.

Comment: Do you just want to track if the user is typing? Or are you trying to load data as the user types e.g. a filtered search or something similar?

Comment: i just want to know when user is typing and if he is typing i need to send "Typing" to server and hence forth if he stops typing i need to send "Paused"

Answer (score 2):

What you can try is have `ng-keyup` attribute included in you `input` tag. So when the user starts typing you set the flag `vm.isTyping = true`. When the user stops typing have a `timeout` in your `ng-keyup` handler, that will set `vm.isTyping = false` after a certain period. Refer the below code snipet

```js
function myappCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    var timoutPromise = null;
  $scope.newMessage = "";
    $scope.isTyping = false;
    
    $scope.checkTyping = function() {
     $scope.isTyping = true;
      if(timoutPromise) {
          $timeout.cancel(timoutPromise);
      }
    }
    
    $scope.stoppedTyping = function() {
     timoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
        $scope.isTyping = false;
      }, 2000)
     
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
 <div ng-controller="myappCtrl">
  <input  type="text" placeHolder="Type a message here" ng-model="newMessage" ng-change="checkTyping()"  ng-keyup="stoppedTyping()"/>
  <div ng-if="isTyping">
    typing
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```